# Sum of 2 criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I am trying to find the total of a certain Call Description. The picture is an example but let's say this will have around 300 cells of data. Due to the size of data, it's not practical to do a static sum of a select amount of cells.

[image: Example 1]

As each call description has a possibility of 3 time of day (day, afternoon and evening) - I want to be able to find out the total revenue for a call description in ***Column F***. E.g. Call A with day, afternoon and evening)

Does anyone know who this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try SumIf:

`=SUMIF(A:A, E2, C:C)`

If you wanted to further drill down to Day / Afternoon / Evening then you could use SumIfs replacing Day with Afternoon or Evening (or reference another column of course):

`=SUMIFS(C:C, A:A, E2, B:B, "Day")`